# Apache Drill - connection to Drill in Embedded Mode [java]

Tags: java, jdbc, apache-drill

I want to connect to Drill by Java app, and so far I was trying to use JDBC to do it and I'm using example from https://github.com/vicenteg/DrillJDBCExample, but... 
when I change DB_URL static variable to  **"jdbc:drill:zk=local"** and start app i get exception:

> java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Running Drill in embedded mode using Drill's jdbc-all JDBC driver Jar file alone is not supported.

and so far I didn't found any workaround. Any idea how to connect to Drill in embedded mode? I don't want to set up distributed mode so far.

There is truly not much about it on the web.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you try using this JDBC URL?  `jdbc:drill:drillbit=<drillbit-hostname>:31010`

Comment: im using embedded mode, so I dont start drillbit as far as i know

Comment: When you use embedded mode, you are starting a drillbit, it just does so without requiring a zookeeper instance.

Comment: @vicenteg   this error is shown on changing JDBC URL: No suitable driver found for dbc:drill:drillbit=localhost:31010

Answer (score 11):

If you are connecting to a local embedded instance(without Zookeeper), you should use drillbit host directly like:

```
jdbc:drill:drillbit=<drillbit-host>:[port]
```

eg:
 `jdbc:drill:drillbit=localhost`

Comment: This is working well for me on Squirrel & SQLWorkbench as well

Answer (score 7):

TLDR: 
**jdbc:drill:drillbit=localhost:31010**

First try using SQuirreL SQL client.

I am doing this with a vm running linux and apache, if this is all on one host you can replace with localhost.

first start drill-embedded on your vm or host eg:

/opt/apache-drill-1.1.0/bin/drill-embedded

this will start the embedded shell. check the port is open - it looks to be a different default than zookeeper etc:

sroot@localhost:/opt/apache-drill-1.1.0/bin [1089] netstat -anp | grep 31010

tcp        0      0 ::ffff:0.0.0.0:31010        :::*                        LISTEN      12934/java

you should be able to telnet localhost 31010 to this port.

you have to setup the jar driver as described here : 
https://drill.apache.org/docs/using-jdbc-with-squirrel-on-windows/

make sure the jar with the driver is executable.

but modify the string with the below - its different without zookeeper, eg in squirrel should look like this (thanks to others answers above too

**jdbc:drill:drillbit=localhost:31010**

you can replace localhost with the ip above - then test the connection.

the jar i'm using is the drill-jdbc-all-1.1.0.jar and the classname is org.apache.drill.jdbc.Driver

[example squirrel driver configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XF2FN.png)

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you r using the correct jar. It seems you are using jdbc-all-jar. There are two jars. You need to add the other jar to make it work. Have added the maven pom. this should get you going

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.drill.exec</groupId>
      <artifactId>drill-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.drill.exec`   for now. But its something new!

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the following dependency in your java project (*I assume maven based*)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.drill.exec</groupId>
    <artifactId>drill-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Sample code (**Assuming you want to run drill in embedded mode**):

```
Class.forName("org.apache.drill.jdbc.Driver");
Connection connection =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:drill:zk=localhost");
Statement st = connection.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * from cp.`employee`");
while(rs.next()){
System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
}
```

If you already started drill (*assumning drill is running on local machine*). Then you should change Connection:

```
Connection connection =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:drill:drillbit=localhost");
```

Check sample project: https://github.com/devender-yadav/DrillJDBC

> NOTE: I have tested this for Drill 1.2, 1.3 and 1.4

Comment: For both the options, do i need to explicitly start the drill ? or in the first option it will start automatically in embedded mode?