# Interfacing Apache Drill vs OpenOffice/LibreOffice via JDBC

Tags: jdbc, libreoffice, apache-drill

I am trying to use **LibreOffice** as a frontend on the **Drill DB** engine, through JDBC interface. Currently I am working in embedded mode, then I will switch to distributed mode.
Drill is working fine in CLI or GUI interface.
I am using **Oracle JRE 1.7**
I have registered the Java class `org.apache.drill.jdbc.Driver`, and it is found correctly.
But as soon as I try the connection the answer is always

> "java.lang.NullPointerException".
>   "Reference Handler" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fc64c140800 nid=0x916 in Object.wait() [0x00007fc63f2f1000] java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor) at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method) - waiting on <0x00000000d7704470> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock) at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503) at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:133) - locked <0x00000000d7704470> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
>   "VM Thread" prio=10 tid=0x00007fc64c13c000 nid=0x915 runnable "GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007fc64c02b000 nid=0x911 runnable "GC task thread#1 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007fc64c02d000 nid=0x912 runnable "GC task thread#2 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007fc64c02f000 nid=0x913 runnable "GC task thread#3 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007fc64c030800 nid=0x914 runnable "VM Periodic Task Thread" prio=10 tid=0x00007fc64c17c800 nid=0x91d waiting on condition JNI global references: 145

Same JDBC interface seems to work in Squirrel, and it opens correctly.

Has anybody managed to work it out?
An help would be highly appreciated.

Let me add some clue (thanks Mark, thanks Jim).
I am just using LibreOffice Base as an application, as it comes out from Ubuntu Desktop.
Here's some detail :
LibreOffice : Versione: 4.2.8.2
Build ID: 420m0(Build:2)

riccardo@coccodrill:~$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_80"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_80-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.80-b11, mixed mode)

riccardo@coccodrill:~$ uname -a
Linux coccodrill 3.19.0-30-generic #34~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 2 22:09:39 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Mark, sorry, I  don't know how to retrieve the stacktrace of the NullPointer Exception, since I am not writing an app, so I have no development environment around me. Sort of working blind, I suppose.

Comment: A NullPointerException is too generic, we at least need to have the stacktrace to have any idea of the problem; and even then it might be impossible to tell without in depth knowledge of both the driver and the LibreOffice JDBC integration.

Comment: "VM Thread" prio=10 tid=0x00007fc64c13c000 nid=0x915 runnable 

"GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007fc64c02b000 nid=0x911 runnable 

"GC task thread#1 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007fc64c02d000 nid=0x912 runnable 

"GC task thread#2 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007fc64c02f000 nid=0x913 runnable 

"GC task thread#3 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007fc64c030800 nid=0x914 runnable 

"VM Periodic Task Thread" prio=10 tid=0x00007fc64c17c800 nid=0x91d waiting on condition 

JNI global references: 145

Comment: Those don't really help as they are threads of the JVM background tasks and not the stacktrace of the NullPointerException. And please, if you have additional information, then add it to your question, don't post it in a comment as it is harder to read.

Comment: Also please provide a few relevant lines from your code.  Are you creating a LibreOffice extension or running LibreOffice externally?  Also let us know the version of LibreOffice, and whether LibreOffice and the JRE are 32- or 64-bit.  It could be that when it was working, you were using a different version.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not compatible. I tried to do the same, but with newer versions (Apache Drill 1.7 and LibreOffice 5.1), and it showed this error: `Running Drill in embedded mode using Drill's jdbc-all JDBC driver Jar file alone is not supported.`

But I did get it working with ODBC driver instead.

Similar issue here: [Apache Drill - connection to Drill in Embedded Mode [java]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31654658/apache-drill-connection-to-drill-in-embedded-mode-java)