# Apache Drill JDBC not working with all default on Windowns 10

Tags: java, jdbc, apache-drill

I am having trouble with making JDBC connection work. Your help will be much appreciate.

1. Installed Drill on Windows 10 Pro, ODBC driver, up and running on
   local node (as in
   https://drill.apache.org/docs/drill-in-10-minutes/)
2. Can able to connect and query from Drill Explorer using ODBC.

---

Drill Shell:

[image: Drill Shell]

JDBC:

[image: JDBC]

Alias:

[image: Alias]

But when I try to connect from SQuirreL as in (https://drill.apache.org/docs/using-jdbc-with-squirrel-on-windows/), it is not working.
I am using the /jars/jdbc-driver/drill-jdbc-all-.jar for JDBC connection.

```
java.io.IOException: Failure to connect to the zookeeper cluster service within the allotted time of 10000 milliseconds.
at oadd.org.apache.drill.exec.coord.zk.ZKClusterCoordinator.start(ZKClusterCoordinator.java:123)
at oadd.org.apache.drill.exec.client.DrillClient.connect(DrillClient.java:327)
at org.apache.drill.jdbc.impl.DrillConnectionImpl.<init>(DrillConnectionImpl.java:158)
at org.apache.drill.jdbc.impl.DrillJdbc41Factory.newDrillConnection(DrillJdbc41Factory.java:72)
at org.apache.drill.jdbc.impl.DrillFactory.newConnection(DrillFactory.java:69)
at oadd.org.apache.calcite.avatica.UnregisteredDriver.connect(UnregisteredDriver.java:143)
at org.apache.drill.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:72)
at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.fw.sql.SQLDriverManager.getConnection(SQLDriverManager.java:133)
at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.mainframe.action.OpenConnectionCommand.executeConnect(OpenConnectionCommand.java:167)
at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.mainframe.action.OpenConnectionCommand.access$000(OpenConnectionCommand.java:45)
at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.mainframe.action.OpenConnectionCommand$1.run(OpenConnectionCommand.java:104)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot use the ZooKeeper "local" since you are coming from an "external" source via JDBC. Try changing that to "localhost" or your hostname.

Comment: Thank you tobi6 for your suggestion. I have tried possible combination like using <IP>, <Hostname>, localhost. Seems non is working.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, this post help my problem. [Apache Drill - connection to Drill in Embedded Mode [java]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31654658/apache-drill-connection-to-drill-in-embedded-mode-java)

By using, jdbc:drill:drillbit=192.xxx.xxx.xxx when drill is running, I can connect successfully..